# keyboard not working within Apps

Tags: keyboard, macos

After upgrading my Macbook Pro to El Capitan, my keyboard stops working from time to time, but within a particular App. The strange thing is the even though I can't type, I can still save and execute App shortcuts. 
Then the only way to make it work again is to close the App and open it again. This has happened me with Xcode, Textedit and TexShop. I was wondering if someone is facing the same issue and if there's a solution to this problem as I can't seem to find one on the internet.

Comment: I don’t have enough rep to add this as a comment, but did you ever find a solution to this? The exact same thing happens to me from time to time. (And if it makes any difference, I’m running OS X 10.11.6.)

Comment: The problem went away with the last version of Mac OS X